# Railo, XAMPP: Where is the apache.ctl or apache2.ctl?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, xampp, railo, cfml

In a weeks long futile attempt to conjure up a basic. PHP application, I've decided that perhaps I'll try this CFML thing.

I already have XAMPP installed and figured I would only need to install Railo on my system. At one point, the GUI installer asks for /usr/sbin/apache.ctl to be confirmed for its use but no such file exists on my system, hidden or otherwise.

Does XAMPP not need/have that file by default? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score -1):

Railo and XAMPP...you can do this but Railo has a nice portable all encompassing download that uses Jetty.

Railo Express: https://github.com/getrailo/railo/wiki/Installation-ExpressJetty

Which is the best way to get up to speed on the CFML or cfscript version of coldfusion.

If you are on windows you can click the start.bat file. This will start the service where you can the navigate to localhost:8888 and you should.see you admin screen.

Railo and Coldfusion are a language and a server (service).

Behind the scenes there is a file structure you can follow and put your files that you are testing with.  The link above should give you the basics to get started.

I would first test the wwwroot is picking up your files by making a simple index.html file and navigate to it through your browser.

The add a index.cfm with a simple Coldfusion hello world.

The you can dig in and get a database configured through the admin section and make some pages that do some database calls.

Oh...and welcome to the Coldfusion programming language where you can do a hell of a lot more in less time, make good pay and generally enjoy your projects more.

Comment: The whole Jetty route wasn't what I needed because I need MySQL. I deleted everything and this time installed LAMP via the smooth Bitnami installer. Trying to install Railo and it asks me to point it to the Apache control script that it beleives should be in /usr/sbin/apachectl by default. I have no such file on my system. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Found it! Did a search before when XAMPP was installed and it didn't show up. Deleted XAMPP, installed LAMP and it appears in /apache2/bin folder.

Comment: Ok good deal...got your message. Yes bitnami is slick. I was trying to get you running on the stupidest simple method I could think of considering you are new to the langauge. You shouldn't have to cruft around environmental config just to kick out some entry code. I have bitnami installed (it's the new hotness) but I haven't had a dev need like that. I keep railo express on my pen drive and run it from there...with notepad++ as my editor I have an instant emergency dev environment. I'll contact you soon. We can talk shop and I can point you too the 800 lb gorillas in CF land.

Comment: Right now I am in a place with no Internet (on vacation) so communication is touch and go. I'lI do my best to answer any questions you have...